# Runtime Error 5, invalid procedure or call argument

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign Cell E8 in Sheet"Report" with an Index Match formula with a dynamic range. The range is from Sheet"Data"

I have found the last row (LR) and last column (lc).
The run time error occurs at the last line: Cell("E8").formula = "=...."

This is the code:

```
Sub report()
    Dim LR As Long, lc As Long, first As Long, proxy As String

    Sheets("Data").Select

    'Finding the first filled cell by moving down from A1
    first = Sheets("Data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    'The first row has column headers: Name, ID number, etc... SO I assign it to the next row where the first data entry is
    first = first + 1

    LR = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & first).End(xlDown).Row
    lc = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & first).End(xlToRight).Column

    Sheets("Report").Select
    proxy = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$10:" & Cells(LR, lc).Address & ",MATCH(Report!$C$3,Data!$A$10:" & Cells(LR, 1).Address & ",0),MATCH(Report!$C8,Data!A$9:" & Cells(9, lc).Address & ",0)),'N/A')"

    Cells("E8").Formula = proxy
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Data!$A$" & first & ":" & ...` instead of `Data!$A$10:" & ...`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub report()
    Dim LR As Long, lc As Long, first As Long, proxy As String

    With Sheets("Data")
        'Finding the first filled cell by moving down from A1
        first = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        'The first row has column headers: Name, ID number, etc... SO I assign it to the next row where the first data entry is
        first = first + 1

        LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Range("A" & first - 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    End With

    proxy = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$10:" & Cells(LR, lc).Address & ",MATCH(Report!$C$3,Data!$A$10:" & Cells(LR, 1).Address & ",0),MATCH(Report!$C8,Data!A$9:" & Cells(9, lc).Address & ",0)),""N/A"")"
    Sheets("Report").Range("E8").Formula = proxy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes to wrap `'N/A'`. You need double quotes and because they are quotes within a quoted string, you need to double them up. Additionally, the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) does not accept the same style of cell address references that a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) does.

```
proxy = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$10:" & Cells(LR, lc).Address & _
                ",MATCH(Report!$C$3,Data!$A$10:" & Cells(LR, 1).Address & _
                ",0),MATCH(Report!$C8,Data!A$9:" & Cells(9, lc).Address & _
                ",0)),""N/A"")"
Sheets("Report").Select
Range("E8").Formula = proxy
```

Here is a quick rewrite that gets away from using [Worksheet.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.select.aspx)¹ method and the implicit [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx).

```
Sub report()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, first As Long, proxy As String

    With Worksheets("Data")

        'Finding the first filled cell by moving down from A1
        first = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        'The first row has column headers: Name, ID number, etc... SO I assign it to the next row where the first data entry is
        first = first + 1

        lr = .Range("A" & first).End(xlDown).Row
        lc = .Range("A" & first).End(xlToRight).Column

    End With

    proxy = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$10:" & Cells(lr, lc).Address & _
                    ",MATCH(Report!$C$3,Data!$A$10:" & Cells(lr, 1).Address & _
                    ",0),MATCH(Report!$C8,Data!A$9:" & Cells(9, lc).Address & _
                    ",0)),""NA"")"

    With Worksheets("Report")
        .Range("E8").Formula = proxy
        'alternate with .Cells as one of these
        '.Cells(8, "E").Formula = proxy
        '.Cells(8, 5).Formula = proxy
    End With
End Sub
```

---

.¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

Comment: Cells("E8") should be replaced with Range since it seems to be Oversight error.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Sixth. I was planning to get back to the code for a quick rewrite and only mentioned the Cells/Range in my narrative, missing changing it in the code.